# USB headset mic cuts out all of a sudden

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, microphone, windows-10-v1703

My USB Headset has been working fine for quite some time until today when I noticed that the mic all of a sudden stopped working. The headset works fine, the mic just stops working randomly. The solution is to simply replug the headset and all works well.

However, this issue has arisen after I added an RGB lighting gaming keyboard to my setup (laptop to be more specific). My laptop has 3 USB ports. One holds my mouse, one, my cooling pad, which gives an extra port into which I plugged in my keyboard. Then I plugged in my headset into the usual port.  The thing is, I ran my setup for the first time like this and the mic issue has happened for the first time as well.

Now keep in mind that all of my equipment has RBG lighting (gaming stuff), and my headset is pretty hefty (7.1 surround sound, vibration, lighting). I think that the mic cut outs could be because of the keyboard drawing significant current from the USB port. But this observation could be incorrect considering the fact that the headphones still work even with the mic cut out.

Any solutions??

Comment: *I think that the mic cut outs could be because of the keyboard drawing significant current from the USB port.* - You can verify this fact by using an externally powered USB Hub in addition to USB cables of the proper length.  Although you would be getting USB resource notifications if this was really a USB problem

Comment: @Ramhound I have a hub which has a small barrel jack on its side but it didn't come with any adaptor. Will a 5v 1Amp phone charger be fine for it??
Besides. I rebooted the PC and the problem hasn't appeared yet as of now